# What is VertiPaq and how it works

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am learning the Column Store index (Denali CTP3 feature) and got to know that it uses  VertiPaq architecture for data compression. I got interested to know as what it is , how it works, it's architecture. I checked in google but no satisfactory result. Could any one please let me know in detail as what it is , how it works , the algo/architecture behind this etc.

And how it helps in data compression

Comment: Now that SQL Server 2012 is officially released this feature is officially called [xVelocity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2012/03/09/xvelocity-and-analysis-services.aspx). Maybe that will help you find information on search engines.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a blog post on this that hopefully will answer your questions on column store indexes:
http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2011/08/sql-server-%e2%80%9cdenali%e2%80%9d-project-apollo/

Please let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 1):

> And how it helps in data compression

The compression part works so well because very often data in the same column doesn't vary much. Imagine for example (simplification) a column that stores values from a multiple (4) choice input. There are going to be just 4 unique values in the column store, even if there are 8 million records in the table. That makes the column values easier to compress. That in turn makes it easier to fit the index into memory and thus faster to query.

> When data is stored in column-wise fashion, the data can often be
>   compressed more effectively than when stored in row-wise fashion.
>   Typically there is more redundancy within a column than within a row,
>   which usually means the data can be compressed to a greater degree.
>   When data is more compressed, less IO is required to fetch the data
>   into memory. In addition, a larger fraction of the data can reside in
>   a given size of memory. Reducing IO can significantly speed up query
>   response time.  Retaining more of your working set of data in memory
>   will speed up response time for subsequent queries that access the
>   same data.

Source: [More details on columnstore technology](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3540.sql-server-columnstore-index-faq-en-us.aspx#More_details_on_columnstore_technology)